# How can I create a plugin that adds a stamp annotation with a custom icon using Adobe Acrobat SDK (C++)?

Tags: c++, pdf, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I'm currently making a plugin for Adobe Acrobat via the Acrobat SDK C++ tool. This plugin needs to be a Stamp annotation that stamps a custom icon (either .ico, .jpg, or .png file) rather than the default `Draft` or `Approved` stamps.

I've followed the tutorial on [how to customize annotation appearances](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FPlugins_3D_samples%2FSetting_the_annotation_appearance.htm&rhsearch=annotation%20image&rhsyns=%20&rhhlterm=annotation%20image). However, this only shows how to pull data from a PDF file and display those pages as an annotation.

I've also looked at [how to access non-PDF files](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FPlugins_Documents%2FAccessing_non-PDF_files.htm&rhsearch=ASPathName&rhhlterm=ASPathName&rhsyns=%20), but alas, this only shows usage for text files.

I was wondering if anyone might know/provide some insight on how to make a plugin that creates a stamp annotation that uses custom icons. I need this to be a plugin that can be distributed to others for them to use in their instance of Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: You actually don't need to write a C++ plugin to create a custom stamp from an image file. Adobe Acrobat (not Reader) will automatically convert image formats to PDF during the creation of the custom stamp. Additionally, if you have the image file on the clipboard, you can just paste it onto the PDF and it becomes a stamp. Am I missing something or was there more to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, @joelgeraci. Part of this was due to poor phrasing of my question, but I actually need this to be a plugin that can be distributed to others, not just a one-time pasting of an image. I've since edited my post to make it clearer than what I had initially made it be.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you saying you want to write a plugin that replaces the Acrobat UI for creating custom stamps from any random image file that the user has and distribute that plugin or that you want to define a new set of new stamps that **you** create and distribute those via your plugin?

Comment: @joelgeraci I'd like to define my own set of stamps to distribute via a plugin